# WPF - How to load selected item from a data grid to observablecollection type

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection, selecteditem

```
ObservableStudent selected = datagrid.SelectedItem as ObservableStudent;
```

`selected` is `null` after this line is executed. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: There are 2 possible reasons: `datagrid.SelectedItem` is `null` or its value is not of type `ObservableStudent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must instantiate the collection in the class constructor. and then it should work fine.